# Which algorithm does Marlin use to create arcs?

Tags: prusa-i3, reprap, g-code, algorithm

I'm writing a paper about a plotter (I use a Prusa i3 with a custom "extruder" aka pen). And I'm supposed to write about the algorithms I/the plotter use(s). I tried reverse engineering, but since I'm not very experienced with this technique I wasn't successful. 
So I'm looking for **the algorithm that [Marlin](http://reprap.org/wiki/Marlin) uses for its G2/G3 commands**.

Comment: Have you looked at [Marlin_main.cpp](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/RC/Marlin/Marlin_main.cpp), specifically t,e ``plan_arc`` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm is based on the "Vector rotation by transformation matrix", and this solution is based on a solution from Jens Geisler. The formula for clockwise rotation is:

[image: Vector rotation]

More information about the vector rotation can be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).